# What do the results of Ampere's law tell us about the H field inside a toroid when the coil is localized?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The magnetic field, $ H$, inside a toroid is $ H = NI/2πR$ and $B = \mu H$, if the coil is spread evenly and entirely over the whole toroid. The loop for applying Ampere's law is a circle inside the toroid.

What if the coil only covers a small portion of the toroid as shown below?
[image]

If I choose loop (1) to apply Ampere's law, I will get the same result, $H = NI/l_1 = NI/2πR$. However, if I choose loop (2), I get $H = NI/l_2 >> NI/2πR$. For loop (3), $H = 0$!

In this case, why is Ampere's law seemingly not working?

-- Add further questions

According to https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_36.html, it it assumed inside the core, the $B_2$,$H_2$ are all the same.
[image]

Do you think it is still valid to make such assumption in the figure for the toroid case so that loop (1) can be still used and $H$ is close to $NI/2πR$? Any way to estimate or even sketch how much the leakage is?

Answer (score 1):

Ampere's Law does not directly calculate the magnetic field. It calculates the *circulation* of the magnetic field along a loop.

$$\int_\mathrm{loop}\mathbf{H}\cdot d\boldsymbol\ell=\int_\mathrm{surface}\mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$$

*If* you assume that the magnetic field is everywhere tangent to the loop with the same strength ($\mathbf{H}=H\hat{\boldsymbol\ell}$), $$\int_\mathrm{loop}\mathbf{H}\cdot d\boldsymbol\ell=H\int_\mathrm{loop}d\ell=HL.$$

And it is this which allows you to find the strength of the field: first find the current through the surface, set it equal to the circulation $HL$ by Ampere's law, then divide by the length of the loop.

For a torus wrapped evenly in wire all the way around, the symmetry of the system makes the assumption that the magnetic field is the same everywhere along a circle concentric with the torus valid, and you can use Ampere's law to find the magnetic field strength. In particular, the current through the interior of the torus is $NI=\int_\mathrm{surface}\mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$, and the length of the loop is $L=2\pi R$, so $H=\frac{IN}{L}=\frac{NI}{2\pi R}.$

In the incompletely wrapped torus, the symmetry is broken and that assumption is invalid, so you cannot use this simple expression to find the magnetic field. Looking at the circulation around each of the loops can still tell you something qualitatively, but you will need heavier duty math to find the field.

For loop 1, the total circulation of $\mathbf{H}$ around the loop is the same expression as in the fully-wrapped case: $NI$. However, that circulation is unevenly distributed: the field inside the winding is stronger than the field outside. Since loop 2 also has the same circulation of $\mathbf{H}$, but only contains part of loop 1, you can also deduce that there is now a radial component to the field (along the straight-line parts of loops 2 and 3).

In the fully wound case, the current and circulation would be proportionally reduced for loop 2 compared to loop 1, implying that the contribution of the radial part of loop 2 to the circulation is 0, and, with a little more thinking, that the field indeed vanishes along those radial lines. But the incomplete winding means that the field now leaks out into this space.

I don't think loop 3 tells you anything much more. There's should still be a nonzero $\mathbf{H}$ field (almost?) everywhere on loop 3, but the circulation happens to cancel out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is very helpful. I assumed that the field is concentrated inside the toroid without much leakage.
I added a few follow-up questions in the original one.